# What is wrong with this md5 implementation

Tags: python, hash, cryptography, md5

What is wrong with this md5 implementation

I tried all the possible thing to get it working but wrong result compared to the pseudocode given in article.
Does this is because of different encoding System.
Any Help Would be appreciated.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Algorithm

```py
#This Code has one to one correspondance with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Algorithm psuedocode
#-------------Globals Start ----------------------#
from math import sin , floor 
import math
S = [
    7, 12, 17, 22, 7, 12, 17, 22, 7, 12, 17, 22, 7, 12, 17, 22,
    5, 9, 14, 20, 5, 9, 14, 20, 5, 9, 14, 20, 5, 9, 14, 20,
    4, 11, 16, 23, 4, 11, 16, 23, 4, 11, 16, 23, 4, 11, 16, 23,
    6, 10, 15, 21, 6, 10, 15, 21, 6, 10, 15, 21, 6, 10, 15, 21
]

K = [floor(abs(math.sin(i + 1)) * (2 ** 32)) & 0xFFFFFFFF for i in range(64)]

rotate = lambda x,n:((x << n) | (x >> (32 - n))) & 0xFFFFFFFF
#-------------Globals End------------------------#
    
def md5(text):
    a0 = 0x67452301
    b0 = 0xefcdab89
    c0 = 0x98badcfe
    d0 = 0x10325476
    length  = len(text)
    text = text + b'\x80'
    text += (b'\x00' * (512 - (len(text) * 8 % 512)))
    text = text +  length.to_bytes(8, 'little')
    for i in range(0, len(text), 64):
        chunk = text[i:i+64]
        M = [int.from_bytes(chunk[j:j+4], 'little') for j in range(0, 64, 4)]
        A = a0
        B = b0
        C = c0
        D = d0
        for j in range(64):
            if 0 <= j <= 15:
                F = (B & C) | ((~B) & D)
                g = j
            elif 16 <= j <= 31:
                F = (D & B) | ((~D) & C)
                g = ((5 * j) + 1) % 16
            elif 32 <= j <= 47:
                F = B ^ C ^ D
                g = ((3 * j) + 5) % 16
            elif 48 <= j <= 63:
                F = C ^ (B | (~D))
                g = (7 * j) % 16

            F = (F + A + K[j] + M[g]) & 0xFFFFFFFF
            A, D, C, B = D, C, B, (B + rotate(F, S[j])) & 0xFFFFFFFF
        a0 = (a0 + A) & 0xFFFFFFFF
        b0 = (b0 + B) & 0xFFFFFFFF
        c0 = (c0 + C) & 0xFFFFFFFF
        d0 = (d0 + D) & 0xFFFFFFFF
    result = (a0.to_bytes(4, 'little') +
              b0.to_bytes(4, 'little') +
              c0.to_bytes(4, 'little') +
              d0.to_bytes(4, 'little'))

    return result.hex()
text = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'.encode("utf-8")
print(md5(text))
```

Output:

```
171e495fea830541b8542c338e388a97
```

Expected Output

```
9e107d9d372bb6826bd81d3542a419d6
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what the problem is, but I think encoding isn't the problem. For example, if you `import hashlib` then `hashlib.md5(text).hexdigest()` then you get the expected `9e10...blahblah` that Wikipedia has.

Answer (score 1):

You are padding incorrectly, the lines:

```py
text += (b'\x00' * (512 - (len(text) * 8 % 512)))
text = text + length.to_bytes(8, 'little')
```

should instead be:

```py
text += b'\x00' * (56 - (len(text) % 64))
text = text + (length * 8).to_bytes(8, 'little')
```

Explanation:

It seems you are getting confused between bit and byte values. Your message is in bytes which means
`len(text)` is the message length in bytes. Consequently, when calculating the amount to pad we need to use byte values.

Similarly on the next line since `length` is a byte value we need to convert it to a bit value before appending it (according to the spec).